# How to change text into text input element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in my page as below;

```
<table id="tbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="field1s">field1x</td>
    <td class="field2s">field2x</td>
    <td class="field3s">field3x</td>
    <td class="field4s">field4x</td>
    <td class="xx">#</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table contains **so many rows**. When I click last cell (xx), I want all other texts in the row change to `<input type="text" />` having corresponding classes respectively, with their corresponding texts inside. And when user again click `xx`, the row may be updated with changed text.

I caught data and made some work already.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/767y4/)** is the fiddle

Comment: Why a diffferent classname per cell? better have different IDs and the same class

Comment: OMG... I wonder Y -1 for my question!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(
        function(){
            // if the td elements contain any input tag
            if ($(this).find('input').length){
                // sets the text content of the tag equal to the value of the input
                $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
            }
            else {
                // removes the text, appends an input and sets the value to the text-value
                var t = $(this).text();
                $(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));
            }
        });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/767y4/8/).

---

**Edited** in response to comments from [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862476/how-to-change-text-into-text-input-element-jquery/10862581#comment14151231_10862581) (below):

> `.text(something)` must surely be faster and simpler to read than `.text("").append(something)` in any case. And you are not adding text but html so even more reason to use just `html()`.

He's right, of course. Therefore:

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).find('input').length){
                $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
            }
            else {
                var t = $(this).text();
                $(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));
            }
        });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/767y4/11/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: simple. if i want to do an ajax request, if any of the text is changed, where should i do that?

Comment: Why not `$(this).html( $('<input />',{'value' : t}));`

Comment: so where can i post y ajax request like `data: "fld1="+field1+"fld2="+field2+"fld3="+field3+"fd4="+field4` and is this possible? can you show the place as a comment in the fiddle?

Comment: @mplungjan: honestly? No reason, really; I just didn't consider it. `html()` would be simpler.

Comment: @blasteralfred: could you add the specifics of the Ajax to your question?

Comment: `.text(something)` must surely be faster and simpler to read than `.text("").append(something)` in any case. And you are not adding text but html so even more reason to use just html()

Comment: Thank you kindly! @mplungjan, answer edited per your suggestions. Thanks. =)

Comment: Ahem. Is `$(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));` not the same as `$(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}));
`

Comment: More or less, yeah; I just chose to explicitly add the `value` attribute, hence the `{'value' : t}` part. It's probably not necessary; I just preferred to do so; personal choice is all, though.

Comment: Absolutely no need for the .val()  at all. It is setting the value twice. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/D44Bp/)

Comment: yea it is @mplungjan +1 for comment

Answer (score 1):

Here's working jsfiddle with comments explaining stuff:

http://jsfiddle.net/767y4/6/

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {
    // active, means we were in input mode - revert input to td
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        // go through each input in the table
        $('#tbl input').each(function() {
           // get input text
           var colData = $(this).val();
           // get input class
           var colClass = $(this).attr('class');
           // create td element
           var col = $('<td></td>');
           // fill it with data
           col.addClass(colClass).text(colData);
           // now. replace
           $(this).replaceWith(col);
        });
    } else {
        // go through each column in the table
        $('#tbl td:not(.xx)').each(function() {
           // get column text
           var colData = $(this).text();
           // get column class
           var colClass = $(this).attr('class');
           // create input element
           var input = $('<input />');
           // fill it with data
           input.addClass(colClass).val(colData);
           // now. replace
           $(this).replaceWith(input);
        });

    }



    // give link class active to detect if we are in input mode
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: its changing to input, but not updating

Comment: @blasteralfred, ah, missed that part. Give me a sec to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version - I felt I should post it since I keep having comments on all given suggestions

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eQZp4/)

```
$('#tbl .xx').toggle(
  function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
      var t = $(this).text();
      $(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}));
    });
  },
  function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
      var inp = $(this).find('input');
      if (inp.length){
        $(this).text(inp.val());
      }
    });
  }    
);
```

if you give the fields the same class, you can do

`$(".field").each(`

instead of

`$(this).siblings().each(`

Answer (score 0):

According to your fiddle, you did almost everything ok, you just need to use

```
$col1.html('<input type="text" />');
```

and you're done, the content of the cells is changed to input fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {
    $('td').not(':last').each(function(){
      var val = $(this).text()      
      $(this).text('').append("<input type='text' value=" + val + ">")
    })
});

$('td:last').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('xx');
})       

$('td:last').on("click", function(){

$('input').each(function(){
     var tex = $(this).val();
     $(this).replaceWith(tex);
})

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/767y4/10/

Comment: the row is not updating. The fields remain as <input>

Comment: What is the point of using on("click') then .click(...) and then on("click") on the same element instead of doing all in one click? Also siblings will choose all the other TDs so no need to test for the last all the time

Comment: @mplungjan yes, it needs `if statement`, i wrote this too fast, thanks.