# HTML: Get value from input with no ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net

Been looking around and I cant seem to find an answer to this so maybe im wording it wrong but here it goes.

So I have a table displaying data from a database. In jQuery I have made it so a row can be added with empty inputs and then submitted to the database, this works fine.

I am now attempting to be able to edit it. So each row will have a button to edit that row, the button will put the row values into inputs so you can change the value and update the database. How can I do this? I was looking into using [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862476/how-to-change-text-into-text-input-element-jquery) but Im not sure how I can get the value of the input boxes without them having some sort of ID.

### jQuery I was trying to use:

```jquery
$('#tbl').on('click','.xx',function() {
    $(this).siblings().each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).find('input').length){
                $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
            }
            else {
                var t = $(this).text();
                $(this).text('').append($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));
            }
    });
});
```

Am I over thinking this? Should I just be grabbing the values and then putting them in pre-made input boxes?

### Update:

**HTML:**

```
sb.AppendLine("<table style='width: 80%;'>")
sb.AppendLine("<tr class='inputRowbelow'>")
sb.AppendLine("<td style='width: 20%;' class='ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>Area</td>")
sb.AppendLine("<td class='ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>Details</td>")
sb.AppendLine("<td class='ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>Options</td>")
sb.AppendLine("</tr>")

For Each w In workItems
    sb.AppendLine("<tr>")
    sb.AppendLine("<td>" & w.area & "</td>")
    sb.AppendLine("<td>" & w.details & "</td>")
    sb.AppendLine("<td><a href='#' class='fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all edit'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' /></a></td>")
    sb.AppendLine("</tr>")
Next

sb.AppendLine("</table>")
```

Comment: There are lots and lots of ways to find DOM elements with JQuery, can you post your html so we can suggest some

Comment: @musefan Im not sure what your after, its just a standard table. If you really want I can update it but any and all ways would be nice to see. That way I would could learn and use them in the future if not today.

Comment: I want to see **your** table, I want to see how each row's edit button relates to the rest of the row. There are so many ways to develop something like this from scratch, but this question is about answering your specific instance.

Comment: @musefan I have updated the questions with the table I am using. This is all in a StringBuilder.

Comment: OK, it would have been easier to see just the HTML output, but that will do. So you want to get the `td` elements for area and details for the row that matches the edit button right?

Comment: @musefan Yes, `area` and `details` for each row (separate) is what I would like to be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, including changing your VB code to add extra data to the html, but I will answer this from a pure javascript/JQuery solution.

First of all you need to handle the click event for each edit button, after that you find the matching row, and then you can get the first to `td` elements of that row...

```
$(".edit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the link from navigating the page
    var button = $(this);//get the button element
    var row = button.closest("tr");//get the row that the button belongs to
    var cellArea = row.find("td:eq(0)");//get the first cell (area)
    var cellDetails = row.find("td:eq(1)");//get the second cell (details)

    //now you can change these to your inputs and process who you want
    //something like this...
    ConvertToInput(cellArea, "area");
    ConvertToInput(cellDetails, "details");
});

function ConvertToInput(element, newId){
    var input = $("<input/>");//create a new input element
    input.attr("id", newId);//set an id so we can find it
    var val = element.html();//get the current value of the cell
    input.val(val);//set the input value to match the existing cell
    element.html(input);//change the cell content to the new input element
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/M24Vw/)

From that you can then do the saving that you say you have already implemented, using the ID values of each field to get the values to save.

Comment: Very nice, has worked for me and thank you for explaining! +1 and correct answer. Good work.

Comment: Quick question, if you click the button more then ones it will fill the input with the input tag.. How can we stop this? (apart from removing/hiding the button)

Comment: @Ruddy: You could have some sort of `isEdit` flag, but I would recommend hiding the button anyway, maybe replacing it with the "Save" button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `For Each ... in ... Next` loop, use a a For loop with a counter. give each button and each row an ID with the current counter value at the end. You can then use Jquery to make each row editable separately, because each row has a row number now.

Comment: I did think about this before but I feel there should be a better way to achieve this. Thank you for your answer.